# How to get to method, by name using IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

While in `Eclipse`, when editing a file, one can quickly get to a method by name. Does `IntelliJ` provide the same functionality via some shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> will show a pop-up that allows you to find a method within current class. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> again includes methods inherited from parent class. For those on Mac, <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> will do the trick.

BTW if you want to find a method in *any* file knowing its partial name, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - works also for fields.